# How to create a local repository for HDP install on Ubuntu14?

Tags: hadoop, installation, ubuntu-14.04, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am trying to install HDP 2.5 on Ubuntu14.04. I don't have internet access on this machine, hence want to use local repos to install HDP as [instructed here](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.4.1.0/bk_ambari-installation/content/setting_up_a_local_repository_with_no_internet_access.html)

After downloading and placing the "untared" files on my server, how to add them to the ambari.repo? How to [Preparing The Ambari Repository Configuration File](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.4.1.0/bk_ambari-installation/content/preparing_the_ambari_repository_configuration_file.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  The hortonworks doc is a little vague.

We are to create a file names `ambari.list`:

```
[Updates-Ambari-2.4.1.0]
name=Ambari-2.4.1.0-Updates
baseurl=INSERT-BASE-URL
gpgcheck=0
gpgkey= <link to local repo>
enabled=0
priority=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just enter your Web-Server URL into the Repofile instead for the Original URL. This is explained in Step three of your documentation

```
[Updates-Ambari-2.4.1.0]
name=Ambari-2.4.1.0-Updates
baseurl=INSERT-BASE-URL
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/RPM-GPG-KEY/RPM-GPG-KEY-Jenkins
enabled=1
priority=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue on HDP 2.4.2.0 + ubuntu 14 and I found that the official documentation is wrong for ubuntu 14. The correct file to be changed is ambari.list under /etc/apt/sources.list.d in the host for local repository. it needs to put local basic URL for AMBARI-2.4.2.0, HDP, HDP-UTILS.

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu sources.list follows this format

**deb URI release-name main**

(details at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine)

so For example your ambari.list should be like this for custom local Ambari repo

deb http://repohost/ambari/ubuntu16/2.7.3.0-139 Ambari main

(assuming you downloaded http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/ubuntu16/2.x/updates/2.7.3.0/ambari-2.7.3.0-ubuntu16.tar.gz under /var/www/html of repohost)